# Upload .CSV file to the website using Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, jscript

I have a website where I have saved the credentials on the browser, When I run the below batch it sign me in to my account and takes me to the file upload tab
[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB13S.jpg) where it clicks "Choose File" tab itself to upload the file. I'm stuck from here, how can I pick the .csv from the particular directory and click on to "Open" from the Windows Explorer? I'm almost there. I have mentioned too many tabs in the script because i have too many tabs on the website.Please help.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer

set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

START Chrome "https://mywebsite.com"

timeout /t 5

%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"


goto :EOF


@end
// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: 99% of your code is not a batch-file.  It is jscript.  Why not just do the whole thing in jscript or vbscript and leave the batch-file code out of this.  This isn't a batch-file question.

Comment: @squashman what would you suggest if it would have been a batch file?